# Predefine the values in a collection variable

Tags: workflow, multi-select, collection-variable

Is there a way to add text values to a collection variable from a predefined list? I have a very long list (>100 items) that I want to loop through item by item but I can't find a way to quickly add the values to a collection variable.

For context, my end goal is to add items to a multi-select picklist based on whether a long text field contains any of the values from my predefined list when a record is created.

Comment: Have you considered Custom Metadata?

Comment: save the data in a JSON string array (in either Custom metadata or static resource) and then use `JSON.deserialize`